# USB randomly freezes on old laptop

Tags: linux, laptop, toshiba

The PC is a ca. 2006 [Toshiba Satellite L 100-113](https://www.notebooks-center.com/toshiba_satellitel100-113.html). I switched from Windows XP back in 2014 and have experienced random freezes since then which I did not see in XP. adding irqpoll t9 kernel params used to help.

Comment: Please define freezing and doing what.

Comment: freezing == mouse - slow or random moves, wifi - packets are lost, even local router is not reached

Comment: Long story short looks like Linux randomly disables or restarts usb hub.

Comment: Which USB hub are you talking about? Also what is your wifi chipset? Please edit the question.

Comment: I posted laptop name. I am using standalone wifi usb module. Well, generally it looks like Linux restarts usb randomly hub or not hub. Sorry i would edit but i am on mobile.

Comment: Depending on the year of your model you have got an Atheros or Intel wifi, none of which is fairly problematic. Have you got more debugging data to add to the question?

Comment: unfortunately not, any tips on that? I already posted model in Source question

Comment: The question is too broad, you might have to do your leg of work I am afraid. It also does not add much to the question saying Windows was ok 5 years ago, I think. Try to add the basics, how much RAM, which browser  you use or what you are doing doing when it freezes.

Answer (score 0):

i did for years. Played with kernel parameters and thats how i realized what was wrong. kernel 4.x causes more aggressive breaking, 3.x looks better.

it happens regardless of actions i take. whatever is plugged in it disconnects randomly from time to time.

edit: sorry it was an answer to talk Above, can someone move it?